# How rude is "naff"?

Tags: offensive-language

"Naff" is a word I infrequently use as a mild version of "shit". If something is a *little* bit bad or dull, it is "naff". I have just come across (via The Slate Gabfest podcast) one of the alleged roots of the word giving a ruder etymology: "not available for f***ing." This is backed up as a possible etymology [here](http://www.yaelf.com/questions.shtml).

Is this word ruder than I though?

Comment: Its origin is probably backward slang from *fanny* (vagina) so possibly ruder than people think.

Comment: @MartinBeckett: I can think of one commonly used word that is much ruder than people think – the word *bugger*. Though these days, people say *bugger off* as a  milder version of *f... off*.

Comment: @branco - "Sod off" would also fall into that category.

Comment: @branco - Yes, and 'piss off' too.

Comment: @5arx - I feel there is a bit of a hierarchy with swear words. For example: { anal sex | incest } > sex > defecation > urination. I'm not sure where religion or sexual orientation fits in here, it depends upon the people involved. This would have "sod off" as significantly worse than "piss off".

Comment: @dave - I agree, and while part of me is struggling to believe I'm having a public discussion about which one is 'worse', I am going to have to say that personally I would put anal sex to the right of incest in your diagram.

Its debateable whether 'sod off' is worse than 'piss off' though. The former was tolerated by teachers during my schooldays back in the 80s, while the former was not. Back then most of us were unaware that sod came from sodomy. This has probably changed though - I suppose the internet has made us much more aware/knowledgeable about both etymology and sex ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a list of the [rudest words in Britain](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2000/12/12/rudest_words_in_britain/), *naff* didn't place in the top 28.  Certainly to my ears it's inoffensive.

Answer (score 13):

Princess Anne famously told photographers to Naff off- so it is by royal appointment

Answer (score 10):

*Naff* is a formal way of avoiding to pronounce the F-word.

It is usable in all situations involving *fuck* except the actual intercourse itself.

How rude it is depends of course a lot on the intonation and the circumstances but it is usually mild (especially considering how common *fuck* is nowadays).  It is definitely less rude than *fuck*.

Here are a few entries from the authoritative Partridge dictionary of slang. Note how *naff* is used as a substitute for *fuck* in such expressions as "naff of" or "naffed up".

> **naff** adjective vulgar, bad, unlovely, despicable; generally
> contemptible; when used in gay society it may mean heterosexual. Theatrical and CAMP origins but the actual derivation is disputed; possibly an acronym for ‘not available for fucking’, ‘not a fuck’ or ‘normal as fuck’; or a play on the military acronym NAAFI (Navy, Army and Air Force Institutes) as ‘no ambition and fuck-all interest’; otherwise it may originate as back slang for FANNY (the vagina or the buttocks), a shortening of ‘nawfuckingood’ or in the
> French phrase rien à faire (nothing to do) UK, 1965
>
> **naff** used as a euphemism for ‘fuck’ (in all senses except sexual
> intercourse/to have sex) UK, 1977
>
> **naffette; naffeen** adjective vulgar, bad, despicable, unlovely. Polari;
> CAMP variations of NAFF UK, 1992
>
> **naffing** adjective used as a euphemism for ‘fucking’. Extended from
> NAFF UK, 1959
>
> **naff it up** verb to spoil something UK, 1981
>
> **naff off** verb to go away. From NAFF; made very familiar in the UK
> during the 1970s by the prison-set television situation comedy,
> Porridge, written by Clement and La Frenais. Perhaps the social
> highpoint of this word’s history was during the 1982 Badminton
> Horse Trials when Princess Anne (now Princess Royal) asked the
> press, ‘Why don’t you just naff off?’ UK, 1982

Comment: Thanks. BTW: I didn't say it comes from "shit", rather it seems to be used as "as a mild version of 'shit'". For example: "'Return of the Jedi' was a bit naff but 'Episode 1' was shit.".

Comment: @dave, Sorry. My misunderstanding. I've heard that a lot: "episode such and such was a bit naff".

Comment: I've never used the word "naff" as meaning anything other than "a bit rubbish".
When I was at school I had a "naf naf" pencil case. Felt a bit naughty.

Comment: @Matthew.  For your information, [Naf naf](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naf_Naf) is a French clothing brand aimed at the teenager market.  It's supposed to be trendy but the people who selected this name probably did not know what the English word meant.  The origin of the name is almost certainly the name of the "practical pig" in the French version of Walt Disney's "[Three little pigs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Little_Pigs_%28film%29)". The characters of the French version are named [Nif-Nif, Naf-Naf and Nouf-Nouf](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nif-Nif,_Naf-Naf_et_Nouf-Nouf).

Comment: @AlainPannetierΦ: Naf Naf enjoyed a brief stint of popularity in the UK in 90s. It is nowhere in the UK now (I prepare to be informed that there is a single store in a large mall somewhere).

Comment: It's worth adding that the reason it was made familiar by *Porridge* is precisely because it's relatively inoffensive. It's hard to believe that career criminals like Fletcher wouldn't swear, but realistic speech wouldn't be allowed on a family sit-com. Ronnie Barker himself (the actor who played Fletcher) came up with *naff off* as a substitute for *fuck off*, *piss off* and similar, and claims he was unaware of earlier meanings, though he could well have unconsciously picked it up from theatre Polari at some point.

Answer (score 4):

In my neck of the woods (SouthEast UK), **naff** almost exclusively means *uncool, tacky, unfashionable, worthless* [*silly, lacking taste*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/naff). I must have heard it used thousands of times by hundreds of different people, and on a "rudeness" scale it's no different to any of those synonyms (i.e. - it's a bit slangy, but not at all "rude").

When Princess Anne told some photographers to "Naff Off!", it was much-reported at the time. I never knew of that usage before then, and I haven't heard it since except in parody of that royal original. I've always assumed that was just a *very* local idiom used only by a small (albeit exhalted) upper-class social clique.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that widely used any more, but isn't in any sense obscure. It seems to be considered fit for print and broadcast in "quality" media. Over all, not considered rude (beyond indicating something is in poor quality or taste), notwithstanding any etymology.

Comment: *The Guardian* is certainly quality media, and is famous for being perfectly happy to print far ruder words than *naff*.

Comment: I'm not sure what point you're trying to make.

Comment: Just that being "fit for print" doesn't *necessarily* mean a word isn't rude. Still, *naff* isn't rude.

Comment: The Guardian *used to be* a quality paper.

Answer (score 0):

Naff originally comes from the underground language called Polari. This was used by gay people in the 1950's in London's Soho district to converse, without outsiders understanding what was being said.
The original meaning of NAFF was therefore a gay abbreviation of Not Available For a Fuck.                                           It ha since been hijacked for other use.

Comment: Supporting evidence would be niffy.

Answer (score 0):

Naff is not particularly rude, but it is slang and so I wouldn't expect it to be used in writing unless it is being quoted as direct speech or unless the writer is using a slangy and colloquial register.